# Performance Counters per guest in KVM

Tags: intel, performancecounter, kvm, hypervisor

My objective is to find the number of instructions after every interrupt delivered to the guest in KVM.
I use the instruction retired counter by programming the appropriate registers using wrmsr. I enable the counter before vmlaunch/vmresume instruction and disable it on a vmexit that is on return. The approach is not good as it also counts instructions in host interrupts and other processes also. I use kvm on intel I3 processor. Is there any provision available to get counters only in the guest mode in Intel Architecture?

Answer (score 2):

I do not have the complete information to answer your question, but these links might help:

- http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization/ch34s02.html
- http://www.mail-archive.com/kvm@vger.kernel.org/msg40722.html
- http://clalance.blogspot.com/2009/01/kvm-performance-tools.html